# An introductory measure theory problem

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Define $\mu_0: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow[0,\infty]$ by
$\mu_0(E):=\sup\{ \mu(F): F \in \mathcal{F}(E) \}$, where $\mathcal{F}(E):= \{ F \in \mathcal{M}: F \subseteq E \text{ and } \mu(F) < \infty \}$.

Prove that if $\mu(E) < \infty$, then $\mu_0(E) = \mu(E)$

It is obvious to me that $\mu_0(E) \geq \mu(E)$ as $\mu_0(E)$ is defined through supremum, but I have no clue how to prove the reverse inequality.

Thank you.

Comment: $\mu (E) \leq \infty$ says nothing. Do you mean $\mu (E) <\infty$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the typo. It is corrected.

Comment: There are two  more typos. Be careful with strict inequalites and loose inequalities.

Comment: Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E \in \mathcal{M}$.  By definition of supremum, for any $\epsilon>0$ given there exists $F \in \mathcal{F}(E)$ such that
$$ \mu_{0}(E) - \epsilon < \mu(F).$$
(Observe that if $\mu(E) = \infty$ the above claim is not possible since $\mu_0(E)\geq \mu(E)$ and $\mu(F)< \infty$ by definition)
Since $F \subseteq E$, we get that $\mu(F) \leq \mu(E)$ and then
$$ \mu_0(E) - \epsilon < \mu(E).$$
Since this is valid for any $ \epsilon >0$, we can conclude that $\mu_{0}(E) \leq \mu(E).$